# asp.net redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

If I have set the forms authentication timeout to 30 days (in minutes) and I have set the session timeout to 5 mins and I am using a cookie to persist the different session variables .. why does asp.net or IIS always always issue a 302 and redirects  to the login page when the session times out ?
(Doing http debugging it puts an "object moved to here" message)

I am checking the session in all page_init s on all pages since they all inherit from a common Page class, if I find a faulty session i load the session variables from the cookie mentioned above.

My question is, who or what is redirecting to the login page!!?

I have tested this on IIS6 & IIS7 with identical results.

I have put breakpoints on every single redirect statement and they never fired, and hence I have concluded that something else is issuing those redirects.

further debbuging revealed the following:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

But I guess that is natural since it is issuing a redirect anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the forms authentication that does this. If you are not authenticated forms authentication will send you to the loginurl.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

The reason why you cannot debug this is that forms authentication takes the request before it gets to your code.

It is also covered at the end of [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443) article

**Edit**

From the second link above:

> Issue scenario: The forms
>   authentication may time out before the
>   timeout attribute value that is set in
>   the configuration file If the forms
>   authentication ticket is manually
>   generated, the time-out property of
>   the ticket will override the value
>   that is set in the configuration file.
>   Therefore, if that value is less than
>   the value in the configuration file,
>   the forms authentication ticket will
>   expire before the configuration file
>   timeout attribute value and
>   vice-versa. For example, let's assume
>   that the timeout attribute is
>   set to 30 in the Web.config file and
>   the Expiration value of the ticket is
>   set to 20 minutes. In this case, the
>   forms authentication ticket will
>   expire after 20 minutes and the user
>   will have to log on again after that.

Comment: but shouldn't it be authenticated since I am using a BIG timeout value? How do I get around this?

Comment: Try increasing the session timeout, forms authentication uses the session not just the cookie.

Comment: problem is, we are getting null session variables for random reasons and hence the cookie that I am using to persist the session variables

Comment: when this happens do all users get thrown out or just one?

Comment: all users are thrown out, but i don't think it is related to an IIS recycle