# Redirect on Login page when user is not logged

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am making ASP.NET MVC2 application.I have login page and just one more page with a table.Page with the table is shown after the user logged in.What is the best way to redirect user on login page if he tries to go on page with the table now?

Comment: Check the first answer in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953731/asp-net-redirecting-to-login-page. There is an interesting link to a MSDN help tutorial page.

Comment: You need to use AuhtorizeAttribute. Post your Controller(s), so I can tell you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put [Authorize] attribute on the top of your controller

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController: Controller
{

public ActionResult YourTable()
{

return View();
}

}
```

Or on the top of your action:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{

[Authorize]
public ActionResult YourTable()
{

return View();
}

}
```